# Convolution in Probability - from discrete to continuous

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent integer-valued random variables,
with distribution functions $m_1(x)$ and $m_2(x)$ respectively. Then the convolution of $m_1(x)$ and $m_2(x)$ is the distribution function $m_3 = m_1 * m_2$ given by:

$m_{3}(j)=\sum_{k}m_{1}(j-k)m_{2}(k)$

**Until this i have understood everything.**

Now, what are the detailed calculations ('from discrete sum to integral') that allow us to go from the equation written above to the continuos one ?

$(f*g)(z) = \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty } f(z-y)g(y)dy$

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "go from"? Both equations are simply definitions of convolutions on different domains.

Comment: The fact is that i have understood the first formula (discrete one) but not the second (continuous one). So, i think that if someone explicitely show me how to go from the discrete to the continuous case i can understand deeply also the second formula

Comment: I don't think there is a direct route from discrete (density wrt counting measure) to continuous (density wrt Lebesgue measure).

Answer (score 0):

In what follows Lebesgue measures are involved. If counting measures are involved then we get the same result for PMF's.

There is - as far as I know - no route that deduces the case of Lebesgue measures from the case of counting measures.

In other words: there is no road "from discrete to continuous" concerning densities.

---

Let $f$ denote the PDF of random variable $X$ and let $g$ the PDF of random variable $Y$ and let $X,Y$ be independent.

Substitution of $z=x+y$ in: $$\int1_{\left(-\infty,t\right]}\left(z\right)f\left(z-y\right)g\left(y\right)dz$$
gives: $$\int1_{\left(-\infty,t\right]}\left(x+y\right)f\left(x\right)g\left(y\right)dx$$

Further: $$\int\int1_{\left(-\infty,t\right]}\left(z\right)f\left(z-y\right)g\left(y\right)dzdy=\int\int1_{\left(-\infty,t\right]}\left(z\right)f\left(z-y\right)g\left(y\right)dydz=$$$$\int_{-\infty}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(z-y\right)g\left(y\right)dydz$$

and: $$\int\int1_{\left(-\infty,t\right]}\left(x+y\right)f\left(x\right)g\left(y\right)dxdy=P\left(X+Y\leq t\right)$$

So: $$P\left(X+Y\leq t\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(z-y\right)g\left(y\right)dydz$$
showing that the function $z\mapsto\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(z-y\right)g\left(y\right)dy$
serves as PDF of $X+Y$.